# Comparing date values of CURDATE() with a full timestamp field

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp

I have a function that is placing timestamp values (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) into `META_VALUE` column of table `META`.

What I want to do is to compare whether the date portion (YYYY-MM-DD) of the `META_VALUE` is equal to today (CURDATE()), disregarding the hour, minute and second (HH:MM:SS).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE <timestamp-field> BETWEEN 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00' AND 'YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59'
```

Allways avoid doing calculations on the field if possible: e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(<timestamp-field>) = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

will calculate DATE() for ALL rows in that table, so you are really talking wasted cycles here

Comment: Or `WHERE <timestamp-field> >= 'YYYY-MM-DD' AND <timestamp-field> < 'YYYY-MM-DD' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: I figured I might have to do a BETWEEN call, but where do I specify which exact date I'm looking for?  I want the date to be today, and of course, that will always be a different value, depending on the day

Comment: If you want the current date, use date_sub(date_sub(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL hour(now()) HOUR), INTERVAL minute(now()) MINUTE), INTERVAL second(now()) SECOND) for the start and date_sub(date_sub(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL hour(now())-24 HOUR), INTERVAL minute(now()) MINUTE), INTERVAL second(now())+1 SECOND) for the end or TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) for the start and DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 86399 SECOND) for the end

Comment: So... appending this to your original answer this is what I should be looking at:  SELECT * FROM table WHERE <timestamp-field> BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) AND DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 86399 SECOND)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `DATE`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2011-12-29'
```